# How to load an external JavaScript inside an extension popup

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to build a page action extension and need to load an external JavaScript library from the popup (it needs to come from the external domain so that the correct cookies are sent).

However I get this error message:

> Refused to load script from
>   'http://api.flattr.com/js/0.6/load.js?mode=auto' because of
>   Content-Security-Policy.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: Did you add `http://api.flattr.com` to your permissions list?

Comment: Yes I've added http://api.flattr.com to the permissions list in manifest.json.

Answer (score 2):

Using scripts via plain HTTP is no longer allowed for security reasons. See [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538).

From linked page:

> Yeah, we're no longer allowing insecure scripts in extensions.  If you
>   load a script over HTTP, an active network attacker can inject script
>   into your extension, which is a security vulnerability.

One suggested solution is to link the scripts via HTTPS where possible. Another one is to include the script with the plugin itself.