# Chrome extension Cross Domain Request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, cross-domain

I know that this has been talked about many times here, and I have read most of these threads but I can't seem to get my script working.

Problem is that I am trying to use bitly api to shorten urls in google chrome extension. I am saving users login and apiKey in localstorage and before I do so I validate them.

The code to do so is:

```
$.ajax({
        url:"http://api.bit.ly/v3/validate",
        dataType:'jsonp',
        data:{
            login: login,
            apiKey: apiKey,
            x_login :"test",
            x_apiKey :"test"
        },
        success:function (jo, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (jo.status_code == 200) {
                setItem('dg_BitlyApiKey', apiKey);
                setItem('dg_BitlyLogin', login);
                alert('Saved');
            } else {
                alert('Incorrect login and/or apiKey!')
            }
        }
    });
```

I do have my permissions set to `"permissions": ["tabs", "notifications", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"]` but I still keep getting:

```
Refused to load script from 'http://api.bit.ly/v3/validate?callback=jQuery17204477599645033479_1334062200771&login=&apiKey=&x_login=test&x_apiKey=test&_=1334062201506' because of Content-Security-Policy.
```

The script itself works outside the extension so I assume the problem isn't within the script but with the permissions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: On top of that as of 2019 you must make cross origin requests from the background page. See: https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't really doing a XHR request, you're doing a JSONP request on an insecure HTTP resource.  See the question [How to load an external JavaScript inside an extension popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8478245/how-to-load-an-external-javascript-inside-an-extension-popup) and the related [Chromium bug report](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=107538).

> Yeah, we're no longer allowing insecure scripts in extensions.  If you load a script over HTTP, an active network attacker can inject script into your extension, which is a security vulnerability.

JSONP operates by dynamically adding a new script tag into your page and then executing the contents. In your case, the script resource is fetched over HTTP (instead of HTTPS). If your extension uses version 2 of the extension manifest, its background pages cannot fetch non-HTTPS scripts.

**Solution:** If you use the Bitly API over HTTPS, I believe that will fix your issue.  **Send your Ajax call to `https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/validate`** (instead of your current value of `http://api.bit.ly/v3/validate`)

Answer (score 0):

You need to package your app/extension for cross domain requests to work. A hosted application will not be able to do cross domain requests. See:

[Cross-Origin XMLHttpRequest in chrome extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9421933/cross-origin-xmlhttprequest-in-chrome-extensions/9422216#9422216)

Comment: unfortunately it didn't help. Could there be other mistakes?

Comment: There must be some other mistake. Try making a minimal example which simply loads a regular html page from another site, get rid of the jsonp datatype and verify that a simple cross domain call to get some simple html works.

Answer (score 0):

To make Cross-Origin Requests in Chrome Extension you need to Avoid Cross-Origin Fetches in Content Scripts.

Full answer you can found in 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/56929473/3680164

Or in the documentation 
https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/extension-content-script-fetches