# Getting -> Origin * is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

Im making a really simple Chrome extension, what redirects pages what are on http protocol ,to https protocol, if exist. Im on debugging, and i found facebook, what has both http, and https.

The code is here:

```
function redirect() {    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabArray) {  
        var currentURL = tabArray[0].url;               //http://facebook.com
        var httpsURL = generateSSL(currentURL);         //https://facebook.com
        if(httpsURL == currentURL){
            console.log(currentURL+" is already on HTTPS");
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_green.png"});
        } else if(checkSSL(httpsURL)){                      
            chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[0].id, {url: httpsURL});
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_green.png"});
            chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"SSL"});
            console.log("SSL found,"+currentURL+" redirected to"+httpsURL);
        } else {
            //donothing
            console.log(currentURL+" has no SSL");
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_red.png"});
        }
    });
}
```

**ajax call:**

```
function checkSSL(url){
    $.support.ajax = true;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function()
        {
            return false;
        },
        success: function()
        {
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, that i get in console the following error msg:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.facebook.com/. Origin chrome-extension://pgidanbjmliilmmohlphbagcapafjjpg is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I dont have any ideas what could be the problem :(

Comment: Seems like your extension is making an Ajax request...

Comment: sry, i forget to copy ajax call, i updated my post :/

Comment: But that Ajax call is the problem... you are not allowed to do it, that's what the error message says. Besides, you cannot return a value from an Ajax callback, the whole setup won't work. You have to find an other way to test whether an HTTPS version is available.

Comment: i see, then how to check whether an url is existing, or not, and return the result?

Comment: Can we see your `manifest.json` file as well?

Comment: sure:
`{
  "name": "Force SSL Connection",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "SSL",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "images/padlock.png",
 "default_title": "SSL"
  },
  "background_page": "html/background.html",
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", 
 "http://*/*"
  ]
}`

Comment: If you're seriously interested in a Chrome application that does HTTP-to-HTTPS conversion, consider looking at [HTTPS Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). Writing it yourself is always a good way to learn, but if you are serious about building a complete extension, you should look at that project (and help make it better, if you want!).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a couple of small issues:

- Your manifest file only requests permissions for `http://*/*`, *not* `https://*/*`, so your request to an HTTPS site is failing.  You need the permission to be **`*://*/*`**, so you can get all pages on all domains *over all protocols*, not just over HTTP.
- A second issue is that you expect your `$.ajax` call to return a boolean, but that is not what happens.  The `$.ajax` call has two *callbacks* that each return a boolean, but `checkSSL` terminates before the Ajax call completes, meaning that `checkSSL` always returns `undefined`.

What you want to do instead is provide `checkSSL` with a callback function as an argument:

```
function checkSSL(url, callback){
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type:'HEAD',
        error: function() { callback(false); },
        success: function() { callback(true); }
    });
}
```

Then, use that callback to run call the code after the call to `checkSSL`:

```
function redirect() {    
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true}, function(tabArray) {  
        var currentURL = tabArray[0].url;               //http://facebook.com
        var httpsURL = generateSSL(currentURL);         //https://facebook.com
        if(httpsURL == currentURL){
            console.log(currentURL+" is already on HTTPS");
            chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_green.png"});
        } else {
            // call checkSSL and take action in an anonymous callback function!
            checkSSL(httpsURL, function(urlDoesExist) { 
                if(urlDoesExist) {                 
                    chrome.tabs.update(tabArray[0].id, {url: httpsURL});
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_green.png"});
                    chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText({text:"SSL"});
                    console.log("SSL found,"+currentURL+" redirected to"+httpsURL);
                } else {
                    //donothing
                    console.log(currentURL+" has no SSL");
                    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path:"../images/padlock_red.png"});
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Notice the changes to the code below the first `else`.  We can't decide what to do until the Ajax call has resolved, so we have the Ajax `success` and `error` functions fire a callback with a boolean argument.  That callback function then takes action based on the value of the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

If you package your extension, you are allowed to do cross domain requests, but not if you create it as a hosted application/extension, see:

[Chrome extension Cross Domain Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10089310/chrome-extension-cross-domain-request/10089368#10089368)